# TikZを使うとGraphicxの画像が消える

Tags: latex

LaTeXでTikZをusepackageするとそれまで描画されていたgraphicxの画像が消えてしまいます。

TikZとGraphicxは同時に使えないのでしょうか。
以下にコードを示します。
ちなみにコンパイルは成功します。画像部分だけが消えてcaptionは残ります。

usepackage部分

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
```

画像描画部分

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{images/hoge.png}
  \caption{hoge}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tikz` パッケージは内部で `color` パッケージをロードします。`color` パッケージと `graphicx` パッケージはともに「ドライバ依存」（ドライバとは例えば dvipdfmx や dvips などのデバイスのこと）であり、なおかつ、その「ドライバ依存のコードを定義したファイル」を共有しています。したがって、`\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}` の時点で正しいドライバ定義ファイル `dvipdfmx.def` を読み込んでいても、その後で `\usepackage{color}` した際に「デフォルトのドライバ定義ファイル」である `dvips.def` が読み込まれて定義の上書きが起きてしまいます。`dvips.def` は EPS 以外の画像形式をサポートしないので、この上書きにより PNG などの他の形式の画像が取り込まれなくなります。そこで、

```
\documentclass[a4j,dvipdfmx]{jarticle}
```

のようにクラスファイルを指定する際に「グローバルなドライバ指定」をするか、

```
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
```

のように事前に `color` パッケージをドライバ指定付きで読み込んでおきます。全体としては以下の様になるかと思います。

```
\documentclass[a4j,dvipdfmx]{jarticle}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{images/hoge.png}
  \caption{hoge}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: 読み込みできました!ありがとうございます!

Comment: @user9156 jarticle の代わりに jsarticle を使うのはいかがでしょうか？